# Retrieve data from sqlite in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have 5 column( `type_id,Type,Quantity,NumberCalories,Category_id`) and I need to retrieve "`type`" according to change "`Category_id`".Please help me his is my code

```
const char *sql = "select type_id,Type,Quantity,NumberCalories from FoodType where Category_id=?";
```

Comment: Please elaborate. what you actually want to do?

Comment: I have tow table"Category , Food Type" I retrieve data from first table and show it in tableview, but retrieve the second table according to Category_id.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the **categoryId** to the database method and modify your query as below

```
NSString *sqlQuery =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select type_id,Type,Quantity,NumberCalories from FoodType where Category_id = %d",categoryId];

const char *sql= [sqlQuery UTF8String];
```